# Isabelle: [simp] leading to an infinite loop

Tags: isabelle, simplification

I am trying to solve the simple lemma "add m (Suc n) = add n (Suc m)" by induction over m.
I tried solving the last remaining subgoal after applying auto by another lemma, howerver if i use the simplification rule on that auxiliary lemma it leads to an infinite loop at apply(auto) in the original lemma.

Do you know why that happens? And if my way doesn't work, how would i solve the original lemma?

```
fun add :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat" where
"add 0 n = n" |
"add (Suc m) n = Suc(add m n)"

lemma aux:"Suc n = add n (Suc 0)"
  apply(induction n)
   apply(auto)
  done

lemma original:"add m (Suc n) = add n (Suc m)"
  apply(induction m arbitrary: n)
   apply(auto)
  oops
```

These are the lemmas in question, i also proved commutatvity of add in a seperate lemma.
The subgoal of "original" after apply(auto) is

1. ⋀n. Suc n = add n (Suc 0)
   When adding [simp] to the lemma aux, the apply(auto) in the lemma original gets into an infinite loop.

Sorry if this is trivial, i am just getting into Isabelle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designing good `simp` rules is an art in and of itself. In your case, `aux` is exactly oriented the wrong way round. You have `Suc n` on the left-hand side and you have something that `Suc n` matches on on the right-hand side, namely `Suc 0`. So that alone gives you an infinite loop.

If you flip the two sides of `aux` it works fine.

A general rule is that in a `simp` rule, the right-hand side should be ‘simpler’ than the left-hand one. In this case it's very clear what that means, but there are other cases where it is trickier, e.g. if you have something like `f (x + y) = f x + f y`.

In those cases the typical approach is to either globally decide that your goal is to push `f` as far inside the term as possible *or* to pull it out as far as possible, and then design all simp rules involving `f` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I read what simp does but didn't think about it in that way at all, i thougt Isabelle just "knows" wich side to use.

Comment: There is some code to figure out the right direction for rules it picks up by itself (e.g. local premises) but even that does not always work. It's a hard problem even for humans.